# Inconsistencies in markdown option button tooltips

Tags: bug, editor, tooltips

The tooltip for the relatively new code snippets feature reads "Code snippet", which is inconsistent in terms of capitalisation by comparison with "Code Sample", "Numbered List", "Bulleted List" and "Horizontal Rule".

Further, it says "Ctrl-M"; the hyphen runs counter to generally accepted convention for this kind of notation, and counter to all the other tooltips, which render like "Ctrl+B".

[image]

Comment: Also, the control command uses a `-` instead of a `+` like all the others.

Comment: Clearly it was added by a different dev than the one who programmed the editor in the first place.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: So? It's trivial to ensure basic style consistency in adjacent elements and the dev should absolutely have done so per fundamental due diligence. In my team this would be a real black mark! Plus, code review didn't catch this? :(